# Execute method on another thread with ToObservable

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, observable

I have a problem running a method (based on `ToObservable`) on a non UI-thread in a WPF-application.

For example I have this method:

```
    public IObservable<ViewModel> Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<ViewModel> vms = _repository.Get();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        return vms.ToObservable();
    }
```

I use this method in the ViewModel:

```
  manager.Get()
         .ObserveOnDispatcher()
         .SubscribeOn(new NewThreadScheduler())
         .Subscribe(result =>
                    {
                        Data.Add(result);
                    });
```

The problem is that method `Get` is executed on the UI/Main thread but I need to run this method on a non-UI thread.

Comment: FYI this style of returning IObservable<T> is an anti-pattern. Checkout http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html to see why.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making the call to `manager.Get()` to be made inside `Observable.Start` and then just do a `.Merge()` to bring the `IObservable<IObservable<ViewModel>>` back to a `IObservable<ViewModel>`.

Try this:

```
Observable
    .Start(() => manager.Get(), Scheduler.Default)
    .Merge()
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .SubscribeOn(new NewThreadScheduler())
    .Subscribe(result =>
    {
        Data.Add(result);
    });
```

The `.SubscribeOn(new NewThreadScheduler())` probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Agreed. It appears that the OP is making their API look like Rx for the sake of Rx. However the code fails to adopt Rx correctly e.g. probably should use `Observable.Create` or `Observable.Start` and accept an `IScheduler` parameter. However, this guidance is sound to keep the API as `IEnumerable<T>`, and only move to Rx where required.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. However, in order to use the `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn` operators effectively, you need to have an observable source. In your example, it doesn't appear that you have that. Once you get that, you can do this:

```
IObservable<TAnything> source;

source
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
    .SelectMany(_ => Get())
    .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Instance)
    .Subscribe(result =>
    {
        Data.Add(result);
    });
```

In your case, `source` will most likely be an observable generated from a button-click or some other event.

`ObserveOn` schedules code that follows it for the given scheduler. So in our case, the first `ObserveOn` call makes the code that follows happen on the ThreadPool (non-UI). The second `ObserveOn` makes the code happen on the dispatcher (UI).

`SubscribeOn` makes subscription-time code happen on a given scheduler. Since your code sample didn't have anything interesting happening at subscription-time, it makes sense to drop it.

Comment: In general I agree, but I specifically would guide people away from mixing `ObserveOn` calls in this nature. Assuming your Rx _is_ written correctly then the guidance to follow the pattern `.SubcribeOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool).ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Instance).Subscribe(result=>Data.Add(result));` See http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/18_UsageGuidelines.html#UsageGuidelines